# Setting termName in Xresources has no effect

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, rxvt

I am using rxvt-unicode on Arch Linux.

`echo $TERM` shows 'rxvt'. If I set `export TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color`, then the colors are working fine. However, I believe it is not the good way to do it.

But when I try to set `urxvt*termName: rxvt-unicode-256color` (or some variants like `xterm*termName` or `xterm-256color`) in `~/.Xresources`, and then run `xrdb ~/.Xresources`, then it has no effect and `$TERM` is still 'rxvt'.

However, if I change another property in `Xresources` (like the font size), then it takes effect for the next terminal I open.

Where could that come from? Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the output of `appres URxvt urxvt; appres Rxvt urxvt` ? Does running `urxvt -tn rxvt-unicode-256color` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your shell start scripts in your `$HOME` and of course the global ones that are often added by the distribution. Perhaps one of them sets `TERM` and overrides your setting. Also check tmux/screen if you use them. They might change `TERM`, too.

Comment: Argh, I feel stupid. I have been checking my bash scripts a few times, and finally I found the wrong definition. And of course I don't remember having set this TERM variable in `~/.bashrc` -_-'. Could it come from some automatic configuration?

Comment: I don't think Arch Linux puts `TERM` settings in default `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

X applications only read resource-settings when they first start up.  Changing resource-settings will not affect a currently-running application.

One quirk of X resources is that if, for example, your system already had a match for the *pattern* `urxvt*termName`, then you would not be able to replace that *pattern*.  You could make it more *explicit*, and override it, e.g., `urxvt.termName`.

Comment: Even a reboot doesn't help... And as I said, I can change the font size using Xresources... Why is it different for the termName?

Comment: A user setting for `urxvt*termName` would override a global setting for `urxvt*termName`. The quirk of X resources that I guess you're referring to is that a user setting does not override a more specific global setting, e.g. a user setting for `urxvt*termName` has no effect if there's a global setting for `urxvt.termName`.

Comment: That was finally a stupid wrong config that I struggled to find =(. Thanks for the point about "*" vs ".", that is interesting to know!

Comment: I also believe it's case sensitive... I had issues and learned it needed to be `URxvt.setting: value`, not `urxvt`.